# Highstock timezone offfset issue

Tags: highcharts

I have an API that is returning data like this:

```
[[1484197227000,55.9],[1484334143000,58.0]]
```

The timestamps are already formatted in the user's local timezone by the server, so I thought by setting useUTC to false, that would work out - in this particular example, the user's timezone is EST. If I take the timestamp of the first data point and see what it evaluates to in the browser, I get:

```
new Date(1484197227000)
Thu Jan 12 2017 00:00:27 GMT-0500 (EST)
```

Which is what I would expect.

However, Highstock is translating this date to 05:00:27, so it's still 5 hours off. How can I get Highstock to just honor the timestamp without attempting to transform it at all? If I turn useUTC back on, then it is 8 hours off. Do I need to do something like write a custom getTimezoneOffset function to subtract out the timezone that the server already translated the date to? That seems a bit odd to me.

Comment: I think useUTC set to false should work. It works in my browser - the result is the same as new Date(). Can you make a live example of the issue? Do you extend Date native object with some functions/properties?

Comment: Have you got the solution for this ?